How could most mobile device antennas not lose signal even if their s11 goes above -10 dB quite often in daily use?
Antennas are sensitive devices. If you place a piece of metal near or put your hands around an antenna, you can see its s11 change rapidly, and its s11 below -10 dB band disappears. I've played with VNA and antennas and couldn't find a way to save antennas from hand-blocking.
How can mobile devices like smartphones and smartwatches not lose signal?
I know they probably have a diversity antenna, but it's quite easy to make all their antennas lose s11 <-10 dB band. I can just place my smartphone on a metal plate, and use both my hands to cover it. However, it can still make phone calls!
I have some guesses:

Textbooks did tell you that as an antenna designer, you should try to make s11<-10 dB. Textbooks didn't tell you antennas can also work at s11=-1 dB. It's just an efficiency loss. At s11=-3 dB, efficiency is 50%, at s11=-1 dB, efficiency is about 20%. An antenna does not lose signal immediately as s11 goes above -10 dB, you just lose some maximum communication distance.

Mobile device engineers can add some resistors on antennas to make those antennas not lose s11<-10 dB condition in most scenarios in daily use.

Today's mobile device baseband chips are very powerful. They have the function of VNA. In daily use, the chip frequently tests the antenna and calculates an optimal path to rematch. Then use its variable matching network to match the antenna to make the communication go again.


Which one is true about modern mobile devices?

Got two helpful answers. One gives an explanation supporting my guess 1, one gives some information related to my guess 3. Then which answer should I accept?

According to the answers I've received, guess 1 and guess 3 are correct. Today's mobile devices have a dynamic impedance tuner that can rematch the antenna if mismatched. Guess 2 is totally wrong.
A -0.1 dB antenna will definitely not work with or without an antenna tuner. A -3 dB antenna can always work and will have more efficiency if a tuner is used.

Thanks to system designers' margins for losses + extensive DSP techniques in the backend.

It's 3. Cell phones have dynamic antenna tuners.
Phones now need 4 antennas operating from 600 to 4000 MHz, plus the effects of hand and body coupling. It's just too hard to get good match without active tuning.
https://www.qualcomm.com/videos/qualcomm-dynamic-antenna-matching-tuner-qfe15xx
https://www.qualcomm.com/news/onq/2014/01/qualcomm-technologies-launches-innovative-antenna-matching-tuner-nokia-lumia (Note the 2013 launch date)

They also have (and have had for decades) dynamic power control. In densely populated areas, base stations are usually close enough together that most hand sets rarely have to transmit even close to full power. So base stations constantly monitor the received power and SNR, and advise hand sets to reduce gain when possible. Improves battery life and reduces interference.

Is dynamic-antenna-matching-tuner technology widely used in today's mobile and IoT devices? Or only high-tier phones are using this technology?

When GSM was the norm in NZ I had a spectrum analyser on the cellphone frequency (due to a project I was doing). I could see signals from cars on a nearby motorway approaching a local cellsite with signals suddenly popping up at max amplitude, decreasing as they approached the cell site, then increasing again as they passed it and then suddenly vanishing. As GSM had clear speech transmitted monitoring the SA output let you hear one side of each conversation for a brief period as they transited the site. You could tune to individual channels with (of course) silence until a car used that slot.

@lotsofone They're used everywhere, for example laptops. There's just too many bands you have to deal with these days.

Is there a good reference book about this field? I can find RF switches designed for this purpose and datasheets about varactors, but can't find a guideline on how to design an RF device or system with a dynamic antenna tuner. And I don't see much discussion about this. The most difficult part I think, is how to design a mismatch sensor. Only with the information from such sensors, can you decide which matching parameter to use for your dynamic matching network.

@lotsofone Reflected power sensors aren't hard, they're basically microstrip directional couplers and can be integrated on a MMIC. However, you may not need to bother with that. When you hand-tune a manual antenna coupler, you simply tune for maximum received signal or just noise, though frequency-division duplexing makes it not as accurate. Additionally, you can use channel-state feedback from the cellular link.


1 Textbooks did tell you that as an antenna designer, you should try to make s11<-10dB. Textbooks didn't tell you antennas can also work at s11=-1dB. It's just an efficiency loss. At s11=-3dB, efficiency is 50%, at s11=-1dB, efficiency is about 20%. An antenna does not lose signal immediately as s11 goes above -10dB, you just lose some maximum communication distance.

You should aim to make S11 as good as possible. The reason is not that 'the antenna stops working', but that RF power is expensive, and you really don't want to throw much of it away on a bad match. Some high power amplifiers can actually be damaged if they drive a poor S11 antenna, but they tend to be more robust than that in phones where poor S11 is a likelihood.
As you point out, S21 isn't hit that hard by poor S11.
Generally communication systems are built with sufficient link margin that calls get through most of the time. The output power of the phone (often +20dBm or more) suffers many losses from its antenna to the cell site receive antenna, the largest of which is path loss. A few extra dB lost in radiation efficiency simply reduces the maximum length of the path that the tower-phone link can handle. Would you notice if your serving cell lost 10% of its effective radius? Do bear in mind that cell sites are planned assuming people will hold their phones, and weak spots are infilled if service is bad and there's enough traffic to warrant it.

2 Mobile device engineers can add some resistors on antennas to make those antennas not lose s11<-10dB condition in most scenarios in daily use.

No, absolutely not. The cure of absorbing some RF power at this point is worse than the disease. Resistive attenuators are used to mask poor S11 in many measurement scenarios, but's that's when precision and repeatability are needed, rather than power and noise floor.

3 Today's mobile device baseband chips are very powerful. They have the function of VNA. In daily use, the chip frequently tests the antenna and calculates an optimal path to rematch. Then use its variable matching network to match the antenna to make the communication go again.

When I was working a decade or two ago in this field, active antenna tuning was a research topic, but as I understood it, mainly so that antenna hardware could be switched between different frequency bands on the fly, rather than tuned up for best possible S11. Such active tuning would need additional space and detector hardware, maybe it could be worth it to implement? Comments invited from people in the industry now.
Phones do do a lot of clever things in their DSP these days. Multiple antennae can be used to beam-form, which not only 'points' a directional antenna towards the cell site, but can also point it away from strong sources of interference. Links are more often interference rather than noise-floor limited. This gains a few dB of link margin over single antenna operation.
Wideband communications, allowing OFDM, are much more resistant to multipath fading, which gains a few dB of link margin over narrowband systems.
Newer forward error correction codes can operate to within a sniff of the Shannon limit, which gains a few dB of link margin over older codes and uncoded systems.
